# ADB Shell equivalent for iOS device - Remote FireTV

Tags: ios, adb, amazon-fire-tv

I'm looking for a way to control an Amazon FireTV TV on an iOS device. I researched and found that most FireTVs are controlled by the Adb Shell method. But on iOS it is not supported. Is there any way to solve this problem? Thanks !

Comment: ADB usually requires an USB connection and a special driver on client (-> iOS) side. I doubt that Apple integrates something dedicated to Android.

Answer (score 0):

iOS does not support ADB. Nor does it have any similar debugging interface: Apple carefully avoids providing tools in that style.

Answer (score 0):

Using the ish iOS app you can install adb as part of “apk add android-tools” then adb connect firestick-ip:5555.

Assuming you’ve already installed remote adb on Firestick.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).